# What's the best way to do multiple requires in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm not sure I've seen this addressed, but I am wondering what is the best way to do multiple requires in a ruby script. I have come up with a couple rudimentary examples which I will outline below, but I'm not sure if there is a best practice for this -- my search results have come back with nothing.

0) Bunch of includes & exceptions (I'll leave the rescue out)

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'builder'
```

1) String array

```
torequire = ['rubygems', 'builder']
begin
  torequire.each do |req|
    require req
rescue LoadError => e
  # Not sure if this is great either
  puts "Missing required gem: " + e.message.split[-1]
  exit
end
```

2) ??

Is there a large problem created from loading them all from a string array? You could specify version requirements or locations similarly, I'm just wondering if there is a problem with doing it this way.

Comment: You don't say why just doing "require 'xxx'" seems like the wrong way to go. Are you going to be conditionally requiring modules? Having sets that load because of mutual dependencies? Platform differences? Also, your "rescue" block serves mostly to allow a script to try to run even if all the requirements aren't there; this is pretty much never a good idea.

Comment: Sorry, I did leave out the 'exit' line which stops the script, I will edit it in. It seems like I can save some lines when I have many gems in a script, if there is no problems (code analysis tools, official code style guidelines, etc.).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The plain way is the best way.

You could do this, but it trades clarity for cleverness--a poor bargain:

```
[
  'rubygems',
  'rack',
  'rails'
].each(&method(:require))
```

Skip the "rescue" with the fancy error message.  Everyone knows what it means when a require throws a stack trace.

If you want to make it easier for someone using your program to have the required gems installed, check out [bundler](http://gembundler.com/).

Comment: +1 "trades clarity for cleverness--a poor bargain", or, as they say in Spinal Tab, "There's a fine line between cleverness and stupidity."

Comment: Wow. While I would never inflict this on anybody else, that's really clever! For anyone wanting a breakdown (and please correct me if I'm wrong), `method` returns a `Method` object and the ampersand calls `to_proc` on it, which `each` then uses as its block. The method signature is used as the block parameters, which turns the caller into the callee. That is, while `['rubygems'].each(&:require)` would call `'rubygems'.require()`, `['rubygems'].each(&method(:require))` would call `['rubygems'].each do |dependency| /* require's implementation */ end`.

Super neat. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

All of the ruby scripts i have seen just list one require per line like you have first.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rack'
require 'rails'
```

Comment: This is what I'd recommend as well.  It's simple, concise, and not too difficult to look at.  Use rubygems and bundler for managing gems instead of trying to roll your own solution.

Answer (score 5):

In the first one it is clear what you're doing.

In the second it requires someone to decode what you're doing.

It seems a bit whimsical to force everybody to decode what you're doing so you can save a few lines of typing (and that only if you're using a whole lot of libraries in one source file which is a bit of code smell in and of itself).  Remember that code is read an order of magnitude or three times as often as it is written.  If it's a choice between easy writing or easy reading, the reading should win out.

Answer (score 0):

```
%w(rubygems rack rails).each { |gem| require gem }
```

or, with a reusable function:

```
def require_all(gems) ; gems.each { |gem| require gem } ; end
...
require_all %w(rubygems rack rails)
```

Neither is popular Ruby style (especially a one-liner function), but Ruby embraces [TIMTOWTDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_more_than_one_way_to_do_it), so use them if they work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best, but if you do:

```rb
def require_all(*gems)
   g = *gems
   g.each {|gem| require gem }
end
```

Alternatively add this one-liner to the beginning of your code:

```rb
def require_all(*gems); g = *gems; g.each { |gem| require gem }; end
```

You can just pass multiple gems to `require_all`; e.g.

```rb
require_all 'rack', 'bundler', 'rails'
```

And so on.
Got the idea from the above answer!